# having trouble getting postgres to work with node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm getting started with Node.js using the Heroku walkthrough which is very good, but hitting a stumbling block with getting the [provision a database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#provision-a-database) step.

When I try to run `heroku pg:psql` I get back:

```
---> Connecting to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL (DATABASE_URL)
sh: psql: command not found
```

which I assume means postgres isn't running properly or something, but I have the elephant in my menu bar telling me it's running.

I can use the psql shell and type commands into it, but when I type `which psql` into bash it does nothing, rather than showing me where postgres is installed.

EDIT: I have added `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin` to my `.bash_profile` (and checked that that file path is correct) but still get nothing from `which psql`.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: I don't know node.js, but "*psql: command not found*" does not indicate "Postgres isn't running". It indicates that your program did not find the `psql` command line tool.

Comment: That is very curious, as I have opened the `psql` command line tool. Do you know how I can tell it where it is?

Comment: This most likely means that `psql` is not in your `PATH`, meaning a typical bash shell can't run it without the fully-qualified path to the executable. Once you find where the binary is located (the `psql` command itself) then add that to your `PATH` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be a path problem, partially to do with me having a duplicate Applications folder on my computer. If anyone is having a similar problem and gets to this point with it, double-check the path!